# Android Shared Database

Tags: java, android, database

Hello I've been trying to develop an app for android dor retail system where for instance there would be a total of 5 tablets in a restaurant all running my app but since in my country retail software must follow a strict number of rules, i cant put a database on each android.. they will have to have a way to access the same database over LAN, bluetooth or other.. I developped a test app with a WCF web service and client app in android but apart from the fact that i have a dynamic IP so i would have to be configuring the connection every time i restarted, it's not very reliable

If somebody could point me in the right direction.. i've been googling for the past week and nothing..

PS: One more thing, this system (retail system) is to be implemented in a number of locations so if possible i would like to make only LAN based connections.. Thanks

Comment: I had to add a netsh command to make accessible my web service to my android app on the same network.. but even with the timeout of the connection set to zero(no timeout), sometimes the connections works sometimes not i dont know why

Comment: Why cant you use a database that the tablets connect to via wifi?

Comment: I wanted the project to be user friendly so the user would not have to configure IIS or apache or oracle or sql server.. that's why the idea of a web service sounded so good and it works fine when i use the emulator but the dynamic ip and the server unreliability doesnt help..

Comment: dynamic ip => use fixed ip or a form of name resolution (dns, wins, ...)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DynDNS  use something like this, you will have an ability to use the same DNS name updated each time you have new ip.
As for reliability, you need to track the reason first. Try to ping the server for some time and gather statistics.

Comment: I was hoping to find something that didnt involve third party tools just some dll's and code ^^

Comment: @Nuno you will not need DynDNS in real production usage, I guess you will have normal domain name and static ip. If your connection is very unstable, just limit the request time and use good amount of retries for each webservice request.